# Getting "OS error 13 (permission denied)" when running Cargo build in a mounted external device

Tags: rust

When running the command `cargo build` on an external device, I am encountering an error. However, I have no issues when running it in the `/home/user/` directory.

```
cargo build
   Compiling test2 v0.1.0 (/mnt/external/testexternal)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.23s
     Running `target/debug/testexternal`
error: could not execute process `target/debug/testexternal` (never executed)

Caused by:
  Permission denied (os error 13)
```

You can follow the next steps to reproduce it:

1. Write this in `/etc/fstab`

```
UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx /mnt/external        ext4    defaults,noatime,users,rw,auto 0 0
```

2. Change the owner of the mounting directory to your user to ensure you have the correct permissions

```bash
chown -R user:user /mnt/external
```

Note: I do have writing permission in the mounted directory

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 user user     4096 oct 27 12:09 external
```

3. Create and build the new Rust project

```bash
cd /mnt/external
cargo new testexternal
cd testexternal
cargo build
```

Any suggestions on resolving this issue?

Comment: Not recommended: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/can-rust-builds-be-done-in-an-nfs-mounted-volume/28191/2

Comment: Since i don't have enough space in my main disk, even if it's not recommended it is posible to build rust projects in an external disk? @kometen

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't had the need. Can you log on to the server and build from there? Only thing I can think of when using NFS the UID must be the same. This may apply mounting with other protocols. Not a programming-related issue as such.

Comment: Do you have two disks on your local machine?

Comment: Thanks for answering but it's not a server it's an external ssd than i'm trying to mount in my laptop

Comment: Aah, then it should work.

Comment: I also think that it should work but i can't get it

Comment: What does `ls -l target/debug/testexternal`say?

Comment: I get: `-rwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4664688 oct 27 13:12 taget/debug/testexternal`

Comment: Try to run it with `./target/debug/testexternal`.

Comment: I get: `-bash: ./target/debug/testexternal: Permission denied`

Comment: Are you sure you don't have the `noexec` mount option set?

Comment: Do you mean in the fstab file?

Comment: No, I mean for the real mounted filesystem (check with `mount | grep /mnt/external`)

Comment: I just run the command `mount` and i get the `noexec`mount option set, but i didn't write it on the `/etc/fstab` so where is the `noexec` option setting?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/678857/fstab-doesnt-mount-with-exec

Comment: That’s what i was looking for thank you